# Python Iteratively Fill Missing Values with Non-missing Values

Tags: python, arrays

Let's say that I have 10 arrays with shape MxN. I want to iteratively loop through each array and fill in values where missing values are located in an initialized array.

For an example, let's take a 3x3 grid:

```
initial_array = np.full((3,3),-999)
array([[-999, -999, -999],
       [-999, -999, -999],
       [-999, -999, -999]])
final = np.full((3,3),-999)
```

I then have a few arrays:

```
b = array([[-999, -999,    1],
           [   1, -999, -999],
           [-999, -999, -999]])

c = array([[-999, -999,    2],
           [   2, -999, -999],
           [   2, -999, -999]])

d = array([[   3, -999, -999],
           [   3, -999, -999],
           [   3, -999,    3]])
```

I would want the final array to be:

```
final = array([[   3, -999,    1],
               [   1, -999, -999],
               [   2, -999,    3]])
```

The logic is as follows:

for final[0,0], there is not a value that is not missing (-999) until the third array, d, so the final value is 3.

For Final[1,0], there is an instance of 1 in the first array, b, so it does not matter what the rest of the values of [1,0] are for the rest of the arrays.

Since there were no values in Final[:,1], these are all still missing

Currently, the best approach I know how to do this would be to loop through each pixel and run 'if-then' loops:

```
for i in range(0,initial_array.shape[0]):
  for j in range(0,initial_array.shape[1]):
    if initial_array[i,j] == -999:
        if next_array[i,j] > -999:
          final_array[i,j] = next_array[i,j]
```

However, as we get more / larger arrays to check, this becomes very slow. Is there a better approach to this?

Comment: please ensure you example if complete, `next_array` and `final_array` are undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a 3D array and [`argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) with indexing:

```
x = np.dstack([b, c, d])

idx, col = np.mgrid[:x.shape[0], :x.shape[1]]

final = x[idx, col, np.argmax(x != -999, axis=-1)]
```

Or:

```
x = np.dstack([b, c, d])

final = np.choose(np.argmax(x != -999, axis=-1), np.moveaxis(x, -1, 0))
```

Output:

```
array([[   3, -999,    1],
       [   1, -999, -999],
       [   2, -999,    3]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.where` to get the indices of only the valid values, then use the indicies to copy the data in reverse order so that `b` has priority over `c` and `c` over `d`:

```py
import numpy as np
final = np.full((3,3),-999)

b = np.array([[-999, -999,    1],
              [   1, -999, -999],
              [-999, -999, -999]])

c = np.array([[-999, -999,    2],
              [   2, -999, -999],
              [   2, -999, -999]])

d = np.array([[   3, -999, -999],
              [   3, -999, -999],
              [   3, -999,    3]])

for arr in [d, c, b]:
    idx = np.where(arr != -999)
    final[idx]  = arr[idx]
print(final)
```